# attach-points functional only on first display of dialog

Tags: templates, dialog, dojo

I'm extending dijit.Dialog and adding in a template:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
    "dojo/text!ps/templates/PrintDialog.html",
    "dijit/form/ComboBox",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojox/widget/Standby",
    "dojox/layout/TableContainer",
    "dijit/form/CheckBox"
], function (declare, Dialog, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, ItemFileWriteStore, template) {

    return declare("ps.PrintDialog", [Dialog, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: template,
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
```

In my template:

< select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="format" name="format" data-dojo-attach-point="formatCombo" title="Format" >

< select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="layout" name="layout" data-dojo-attach-point="layoutCombo" title="Layout" >

This is the usage of the attach-points:

```
this.formatCombo.attr('store', this.formatStore);
        this.layoutCombo.attr('store', this.layoutStore);
```

now, the first time I create a new dialog, it works fine. If I then close the dialog, and create a new dialog, 
this.formatCombo and this.layoutCombo are undefined, and the code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any issue / error of "Tried to register widget with same id.". If some please remove id from both select tag.